# How to draw an object offset from the center of a existing grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to draw an image on a grid of tiles that is already active, by changing the colors of the nodes. The grid is drawn with a double for loop, and I've got an image that fits within that area. At the moment, the image tiles the existing space, but I'd like it to center instead.

How would I position the image using the existing for loops?

```
for (int x = 0; x < maxSize; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < maxSize; y++)
    {
        Node tile = new Node();
        tile.x = x;
        tile.z = y;
        // copyImage.GetPixel(y, x) - The image being copied onto the grid 
        tile.currentColor = ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB(Color.white);
        Nodes.Add(tile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.. Could you maybe add some drawing and exact description of what you want to achieve vs what is currently happening instead?

Comment: I actually solved it, after a lot of pondering and testing. Essentially, the grid is a virtual monitor, and I was trying to display the output of images imported into it and redraw so that it showed the images. Initially, it was tiling the images, but I wanted them centered instead.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing, I did manage to solve the problem. In order to center the image instead of tiling it, it needed a correct offset, as well as image limits:

```
int center = maxSize / 2;
int offsetX = center - copyImage.width / 2;
int offsetY = center - copyImage.height / 2;
int maxY = offsetY + copyImage.height;
int maxX = offsetX + copyImage.width;

for (int x = 0; x < maxSize; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < maxSize; y++)
    {
        Node tile = new Node();
        tile.x = x;
        tile.z = y;

        bool yTrue = y > offsetY && y < maxY;
        bool xTrue = x > offsetX && x < maxX;

        if (yTrue && xTrue)
        {
            tile.currentColor = ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB(copyImage.GetPixel(x - offsetX, y - offsetY));
        } else {
            tile.currentColor = ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB(Color.white);
        }
        tile.currentColor = ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB(Color.white);
        Nodes.Add(tile);
    }
}
```